# Wrap select with an Oracle function

Tags: oracle

In my mind, I'm writing a function such that calling something like

```
select get_foo() from dual;
```

or

```
select * from table (get_foo);
```

returns the same result as

```
select * from foo;
```

So, I've got a function that compiles...

```
create or replace function get_foo return sys_refcursor as
  rc_foo sys_refcursor;
begin
  open rc_foo for 'select * from foo';
  return rc_foo;
end;
```

but select get_foo() from dual returns 1 row.

```
((ID=1,NAME=Sarah1),(ID=2,NAME=Sarah2),(ID=3,NAME=Sarah3),)
```

whilst select * from table( get_foo() ) gives me ORA-22905.

How do I change the function definition and/or the call to get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

you use a pipelined function.

for example:

```
SQL> create table foo(id , name) as select rownum, 'Sarah'||rownum from dual connect by level <= 3;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace package pipeline_test
  2  as
  3    type foo_tab is table of foo%rowtype;
  4    function get_foo
  5      return foo_tab PIPELINED;
  6  end;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pipeline_test
  2  as
  3    function get_foo
  4      return foo_tab PIPELINED
  5    is
  6      v_rc sys_refcursor;
  7             t_foo foo_tab;
  8
  9    begin
 10      open v_rc for select * from foo;
 11      loop
 12        fetch v_rc bulk collect into t_foo limit 100;
 13        exit when t_foo.count = 0;
 14        for idx in 1..t_foo.count
 15        loop
 16          pipe row(t_foo(idx));
 17        end loop;
 18      end loop;
 19    end;
 20  end;
 21  /

Package body created.

SQL> select * from table(pipeline_test.get_foo());

        ID NAME
---------- ---------------------------------------------
         1 Sarah1
         2 Sarah2
         3 Sarah3
```

Comment: Thanks. This is reasonably clear. I'm still trying to get my head around pipelining and packages. Are they necessary to achieve the desired effect? Also, is there any (significant) performance hit in selecting into a cursor and then looping through it

Comment: @SarahPhillips depending on the size of the result set you could improve this by using bulk collect (with say a limit of 100 or so) to reduce the fetches per rows returned. ie something like `fetch v_rc bulk collect into t_foo;` where `t_foo` is a table of `r_foo` then looping round that output array and pipeing the output.